# No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:1.x.x available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, offline-mode

Error:No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I am facing this issue because I am working in offline mode in android studio. Can some body please tell me where is this cached file stored in my windows and from where I'll get this file so that I can separately download it and paste/keep it, and build my android project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Offline mode does not allow you to completely work offline. Its actually a **GOOD cache mode**. Whenever you add new dependencies, You **HAVE** to gradle sync the project, **ATLEAST ONCE**. Android studio has to download(then cache) the dependencies for the app to work. Once you sync the gradle files, then you can switch to offline mode, and you can work.

If you must work offline, then i would suggest determining all the dependencies you need in your application. Add them all at once and Gradle sync. Then switch to Offline mode.

**UPDATE**
If you are working behind a proxy network, then goto File-> Settings -> Under Appearence & Behavior -> Under System Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> Click on Manual proxy configuration, and add the neccessary details. Then goto your **gradle.properties** file which should contain sometyhing like this :

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=your_password
systemProp.http.proxyHost=host_Ip_address
systemProp.http.proxyUser=your_username
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port_number
```

Add this to your file, along with the above :

```
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=your_password
systemProp.https.proxyHost=host_Ip_address
systemProp.https.proxyUser=your_username
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port_number
```

These details can be found out from your browser's proxy settings.

Comment: I have tried that but the issue is
"Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle."
that's why I want to manually download the "google-services" and paste it at desired place

Comment: Do you work behind a proxy network..? If you are, check my updated answer.

Comment: I have already done this even before posting this question.
these are the proxy details and no need of any username and pwd
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.10.90.91
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080

Comment: Did you add lines for https. If not then add the same code for https.==> systemProp.https.proxyHost=10.10.90.91 systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080

Comment: Adding https proxy helped I had only added http proxy. Thank you

Answer (score 70):

you can also do this:

```
Go to `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings`
```

And open the

```
Build,Execution,Deployment
```

Then open the

```
Build Tools -> Gradle
```

Then uncheck `Offline work` on the right.

Click the `OK` button.

Then Rebuild the Project.

Comment: I know the "offline" option but for that particular package like "com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3"  I need to be online since it was not cached.

Comment: In my case the offline option is unchecked by default. But still I am getting same error.

Comment: For Mac, ```Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Gradle``` then uncheck "Offline work"

Answer (score 8):

**Disable offline mode** to solve this error.

**In Android Studio** Go:

`File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`

Then Uncheck **Ofline Work**, Done.

Comment: @BryanKimani Thank you for let me know. Yes, it's also take my too many time to find this solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Disable offline mode**

- Step 1: Goto `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`
- Step 2: **Uncheck** checkbox of `Offline Work`.
- Step 3: Click the `Apply` and `Ok` button.
- Then click `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` and Rebuild the Project.

[image]

Comment: in my case was a command-line options, take a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376069/2238515

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find the offline work option under under `File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`, or you are using Android Studio Artic Fox, try this.

1. Click on Gradle tab on the right of your Android Studio window.
2. Click on the Toggle Offline Mode button.
3. Rebuild your project.

[image]

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1` and you unchecked offline work and still get this Error

Do this:

```
File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle-Android Compiler
```

Remove **--offline** in command-line Options and **apply** and **ok**.

Then click `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` and Rebuild the Project

Answer (score 0):

Update te Gradle distribution, go to the oficial site https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ find the last, in this moment  gradle-5.0-all.zip and download it, unzit this and configure the grandle path in Android studio
S2s

Answer (score 0):

If your **Offline Work** is **Unchecked** and If you still get this Error.

Do this:

**File => Invalidate Caches/Restart**

In my case also I had the same problem. Solved it using this.

Answer (score 0):

`minSdkVersion` can't be under 16, and it works. [image]

[image]

and download sdk tools google services,

click **sdk manager** and then click **sdk tools** and ** [download google play services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7QPg.png)**