# Android Studio 3.1, No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, offline, android-glide

Big problem since upgrading to Android Studio 3.1, I get:

```
No cached version of com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1 available for offline mode
```

But I am not in offline mode as you can see here:

[image]

I tried Clean Project and Rebuild Project, all with no success.
I even rebooted my PC.

Here's my Build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49506100/7229971 check this one

Comment: Thanks KuLdip, but I already had the Gradle-awake Make entry

Comment: JCenter from Bintray is currently down. Maybe your problem is related? -> http://status.bintray.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know what was going on, maybe it was really due to JCenter being partly down during the day. Probably because half the globe was upgrading Android Studio to 3.1.

I cleaned the cache (70.000 files!), no effect, except from a resulting hourlong download of thousands of files, mainly from JCenter, with at least 10 fails (time outs?) along the way.
End result: Gradle still complaing about

```
No cached version of com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1 available for offline mode
```

Then in desparation, I modified

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
```

to

```
`compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'compiler', version:` '4.6.1'
```

in my Build.gradle.

The result was of course an error message.

After then changing back to where I came from

```
compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'compiler', version: '4.6.1'
```

Bingo: all was good, no idea why.

Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Changing back to?

Comment: back to 
compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'compiler', version: '4.6.1'

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue and "offline work"  was unchecked inside gradle settings. After wasting 2 hours on it, I realized that I had --offline in the Command-line options of Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler. So make sure you don't have that command listed there when you encounter this issue.

Comment: Try this answer ➡️ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481987/no-cached-version-gradle-plugin-available-for-offline-mode/60500279#60500279

Answer (score 4):

You should close Gradle offline-work model and clear compiler Command-line Options --offline:

[image: Clear command line option]

[image: Toggle offline Gradle]

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was to remove the "--offline" in "File -> Settings -> Compiler -> Command-line Options".

I don't know why this parameter was there but anyway...now it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

First My English is very poor,Sorry.
I meet this problem too，when I upgrade my AndroidStudio to 3.1 and update gradle 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 ，then I build to run my project，it is error “no version of butterknife in offline mode”，but I'm sure it’s not offline mode。I have tried to  a lot of ways ,doesn't work.
Then I try to add dependences in AndroidStudio `ProjectStructure`--`app`--`dependences`,search and selected the butterknife,and then build to run.
It works!
https://blog.csdn.net/binglumeng/article/details/79747651
I hope It can help you!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried invalidating your cache and restarting your android studio?
or else if your working behind a proxy network checkout this
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747449/no-cached-version-of-com-google-gmsgoogle-services1-x-x-available-for-offline)

Comment: Yes, tried deleting the cache (70k files!). Unfortunately it didn't change the outcome. Thanks anyway