# Android Studio Could not download lint.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.3.3): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android

After upgrading Android Studio from 2.7.0 to 3.1.2 my project could not be built. It says

```
"Could not download lint.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.3.3): No cached version available for offline mode."
```

I have been trying to disable offline mode but it's not working either.
Please help me

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD5lq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not download lint.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.3.3):

You should call

```
 compile group: 'com.android.tools.lint', name: 'lint-api', version: '25.3.3'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild and Gradle`**.

Note

For **`No cached version available for offline mode`** issue you should take a look [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037367/3395198) answer.

[image]

Comment: Unchecking offline work worked for me as well