# android sync error at Android Studio said fastutil.jar couldn't download

Tags: android, android-studio

When ever I create a project, while syncing it gets an error.

```
sync failed 542 ms
Run build   355 ms
null    
Could not download fastutil.jar (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0): No cached version available for offline 
mode
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57699372/3395198

Answer (score 0):

Download the library jar file form hear : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.unimi.dsi/fastutil

and follow the link : [How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio/55790149#55790149)

I hope it'll help you...!

Answer (score 0):

Disable offline mode

1. Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).
2. In the left pane, click Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.
3. Uncheck the Offline work checkbox.

Click Apply or OK and sync the project